# How to install mysql DB while offline?

Tags: package-management, mysql, database

I have downloaded mysql-5.5.9-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz file. I don't know how to install it into my Ubuntu os. I don't have an internet connection, I'm posting here from browsing center. I can download files from here, but I can't connect my laptop directly to the internet. Is there any way to install mysql while offline?

Comment: is the package an rpm or a source code?

Answer (score 6):

When installing things on Ubuntu, you're *much* better off using packages provided for your version of Ubuntu, rather than from other sources.

To install a package offline, you can do something like this:

`apt-get install --print-uris mysql-server`

This will print out a bunch of URLs. You can download these from another computer, and transfer them to your Ubuntu machine, putting the .deb files into `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Once you've done that, do:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

And apt will find the package files you've downloaded, and install mysql.